# How to catch user actions after closing Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I want to catch "don't save" button click on save dialog when user is trying to close Excel workbook, but there are unsaved changes.

**My case is:** 
the user is opening the excel file changing something in the file and clicking to close button, the Excel application will display "do you want to save changes" dialog and I want to handle the cases when the user will choose no or cancel.
**I don't want to switch the screen and show to user my own dialog in my application, the user will not be happy for that solution.**
If there is a way to handle this please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
_xlsApp = new Excel.Application();
_xlsApp.WorkbookBeforeClose += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(xlsApp_WorkbookBeforeClose);
_xlsApp.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(xlsApp_WorkbookBeforeSave);
```

Comment: Do you want to save or discard (or suppress this operations) the changes or leave this decision to the user?

Comment: leave this decision to the user and catch his action when the user will clock on don't save button

Comment: You can't handle/intercept the default dialog and if you handle the event by yourself you need to add your own functionality that mimics the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you need to *overwrite* the default *save/do not save changes* event with a custom one.

In your *before save* event handler:

- check if the workbook has any unsaved changes using the [Workbook.Saved property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saved.aspx)
- if yes, then show a custom **there are unsaved changes - save or discard** dialog and fetch the user response *yes/no* ([example in this article](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip78.htm))
- you can always cancel the save event - [MSDN documentation of the BeforeSave event that shows how to cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- or save the changes using the [Workbook.Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.save.aspx)

This way the decision is left to the user (as default, nothing changes from the user perspective), but you can still do whatever you want to do before or after the workbook is saved.

If the user closes the application excel will go first in the *before close* event. You have two options: 
- check here if there are any changes and aks the user and save the answer and use the answer later in the *before save* event
- or skip this event - if there are any unsaved changes, excel will either way go to the *before save* event, where you can proceed as shown above; from MSDN `If the workbook has been changed, this event occurs before the user is asked to save changes.`

Comment: thanks a lot, but:
1. I've tagged c# 2. this will not resolve my issue because the user will see 2 save changes dialog, one in my App 2nd in excel Application

Comment: The MSDN links are for the object model, that is used when automating Excel with C# - you have a reference of the Excel assemblies that give you exactly this API and the Excel-Link is to explain the idea of the custom dialog! You can use the *SaveAsUI* parameter to **suppress** the default dialog: `SaveAsUI - Required - Boolean - True if the Save As dialog box will be displayed.` (see the documentation). Then you can proceed as suggested.

Comment: ok! last problem in this solution is: the user will see save changes dialog in my App and maybe the user will not be happy for this, but if there is no way to handle Excel cancel or don't save button, maybe it's ok

Comment: You said you want to leave the decision to the user - if the user does not see a dialog, how can he decide? Do you want to show a dialog or not when there are unsaved changes? The solution to this is simple - save or discard the changes by yourself in the before save event - then the excel will not show a dialog at all!

Comment: And what I should do when the user open the excel file, start editing and then click on close button? I will never get before save event, I will get beforeClose event immediately and what I should do?

Comment: When you are in *before close* check if there are any changes using the **Saved** property - if yes, then show the custom dialog - if the user says *yes, save* then save the workbook and excel will not show the default dialog because there are no unsaved changes anymore, else discard changes and excel wont show a dialog neither (if excel calls *before save* event after the *before close* event, then mark your decision in a local variable and check for this variable in the *before save* event in order to cancel it.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Pasty. Your solution is good one but not the best one, because I have to switch the screen to my application and show to user my own dialog. I will wait to another solution. If I will not achieve to my goal I will choose your solution

Comment: You don't need to acceppt my solution if it does not match your needs!I am not sure what you mean with *switch screen*. I suggest you to write down your thoughts / steps on a piece of paper and see what makes sense and what is the event order to plan your solution better.